# Android - How can I print an image (Raster) on a Bluetooth printer (X330)?

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I have the thermal printer X330 and I need to print and image (bitmap) taken from the android Camera, but I can't...I'm always get symbols in the printer.

In the documentation said:

Print raster bit image

- Hex     1D   76   30   m  xL  xH  yL  yH  d1...dk
- 0 ≤ m ≤ 3, 48 ≤ m ≤ 51
- 0 ≤ xL ≤ 255
- 0 ≤ xH ≤ 255
- 0 ≤ yL ≤ 255
- 0 ≤ d ≤255
- k = ( xL + xH × 256) × ( yL + yH × 256) ( k ≠ 0)
- xL, xH, select the number of data bits ( xL+ xH×256) in the horizontal direction for the bit image
- yL, yH, select the number of data bits ( yL+ yH×256) in the vertical direction for the bit image
- If the printing area width set by GS L and GS W is less than the minimum width,
  the printing area is extended to the minimum width only on the line in question.
  The minimum width means 1 dot in normal (m=0, 48) and double-height (m=2,
  50), 2 dots in double-width (m=1, 49) and quadruple (m=3, 51) modes.
- Data outside the printing area is read in and discarded on a dot-by-dot basis
- The position at which subsequent characters are to be printed for raster bit
  image is specified by HT (Horizontal Tab), ESC $ (Set absolute print position),
  ESC \ ( Set relative print position), and GS L (Set left margin ). If the position at
  which subsequent characters are to be printed is not a multiple of 8, print speed
  may decline
- The ESC a (Select justification) setting is also effective on raster bit images
- When this command is received during macro definition, the printer ends macro
  definition, and begins performing this command. The definition of this
  command should be cleared
- d indicates the bit-image data. Set time a bit to 1 prints a dot and setting it to 0
  does not print a dot.

I know that the bitmap need to be converted, but I can't get the correct format.

Someone can help me!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this a little while ago and eventually got it working. My thermal printer is not the same one that you are using but the principle should remain the same. So my printer works over USB and here is what I send to the printer for the image to be printed.

```
byte[] rasterImage = {0x1D, 0x76, 0x30, 0x30, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01};

File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/1.bmp");
int size = (int) file.length();
bitmapdata = new byte[size];
try
{
    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    buf.read(bitmapdata, 0, bitmapdata.length);
    buf.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{

} catch (IOException e)
{

}

connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, rasterImage, rasterImage.length, TIMEOUT);
connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, bitmapdata, bitmapdata.length, TIMEOUT);
```

The rasterImage is basically the setup of the hex data needed to tell the printer than I want to print a raster bit image. Then I read the photo or image from the internal storage of the device and convert it into a byte[]. Then I send the rasterImage hex data and the bitmapdata to the printer.

A few things to note, firstly you need to convert the image you want to print to a 1 bit depth monochrome image, you can use paint to do this (simply save the image from paint as a monochrome bitmap), you need to do this because the printer can only print a dot or no dot, it cannot print layered images etc. Second, you need to make sure that the image resolution is a multiple of 8, the reason for this is due to the xL, xH, yL and yH calculation on my printer, the one works only in bytes and so I have no way to get anything other than a multiple of 8. So my image was 256x256.

Let me know if you have success and if you need more help let me know.

I did not include any USB code, but just use your bluetooth connection to send the data in a similar way.